# how to output a vector to xml in r

Tags: xml, r, vector

I have a vector of integer values. for example

```
vec = c(2,52,12,56,121)
```

I want to write an XML file which outputs these values. For example, the XML file may look like this:

```
<Periods>
  <Value>2</Value>
  <Value>52</Value>
  <Value>12</Value>
  <Value>56</Value>
  <Value>121</Value>
</Periods>
```

What is the most efficient way in **R** to use the "XML" package to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(XML)
node = newXMLNode("Periods")
sapply(as.character(vec),function(x){
    newXMLNode("Value",x,parent=node)
})
saveXML(node,file="try.xml")
```